# How to set activity to fullscreen mode in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

How to set full screen mode for activity in Android? I am using the following code to set full screen but it generates an error:

**Exception:**

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
    requestFeature() must be called before adding content.
```

**Code:**

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,        
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: Hello all , Problem solved when I write code before setContentView(R.layout.main); . Thank you! All for your answers.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

please check the code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

and note it is set before setting the content view

Comment: just change your set content view to after feature no title thats the error shown

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved... Now no any exception in code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might still see another error specifically with Amazon devices. You need to call requestWindowFeature before super.onCreate(). See the following answer: stackoverflow.com/questions/12388771/how-to-set-activity-to-fullscreen-mode-in-android

Comment: Works like a charme. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is there any xml equivalent for this ?

Answer (score 13):

try this in AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Comment: This code I used in MAIN activity. Activity name already declared in AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 4):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: No Mayank this code also not work for me

Comment: **Code:**
   

    public class Draw extends Activity {
 SignatureView sv;
 RelativeLayout rLayout1;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  rLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
  // Set full screen view
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  sv = new SignatureView(this, null);  
  rLayout1.addView(sv);
  sv.requestFocus();
 }
}   This is my code

Comment: @RanjitChandel setcontent view should come afterwards check my code below

Answer (score 2):

put **requestWindowFeature** first in your code....like this...

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Hello all , Problem solved when I write code before setContentView(R.layout.main); . Thank you! All for your answers.