# android activity hide too bar, full screen

Tags: android, aar

I would like to explain what i am doing now. I developed an aar(sdk) and is running fine. However, i would like my sdk to occupy full screen when being called, even the caller has a toolbar. i tried the sample from this link

[[How to set activity to fullscreen mode in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388771/how-to-set-activity-to-fullscreen-mode-in-android][1])

However, if i put the code in android Manifest of the sdk, my app will crashed. If i do it when sdk activity OnCreate as below code. The toolbar still there.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sdk_main);
```

May I know what do i need to do to hide the toolbar. Thanks.

Comment: Best solutions are here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android`

Comment: from your link, i found getSupportActionBar().hide();  is working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

works.

Additional explaination, my class is an extension of AppCompatActivity, below is the code.

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Logger.d(SdkMainActivity.class, "onCreate");
            getSupportActionBar().hide();    //---> this works

    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);   // ---> this the toolbar still appear

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sdk_main);

}
```

Comment: Can you please give a full example and explanation of the code for completeness?

Answer (score 0):

If you want full screen mode for particular activity then use this

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}
```

and for all activities Create a BaseActivity and write its onCreate method as shown above and extend this base activity for all other activities.

Comment: sorry. that's i already tried before posting this question. i tried both add that code before and after setContentView.  Both not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setFullScreenView() {//Hiding status/navigation bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
}
```